# Doxygen RTF disable hyperlinks

Tags: hyperlink, doxygen, rtf

Env:
Doxygen version 1.7.6.1
OS: Ubuntu 12.04

I have doxygen set up to parse some c/c++ files and to generate RTF:

```
GENERATE_RTF           = YES


# If the COMPACT_RTF tag is set to YES Doxygen generates more compact
# RTF documents. This may be useful for small projects and may help to
# save some trees in general.

COMPACT_RTF            = YES

# If the RTF_HYPERLINKS tag is set to YES, the RTF that is generated
# will contain hyperlink fields. The RTF file will
# contain links (just like the HTML output) instead of page references.
# This makes the output suitable for online browsing using WORD or other
# programs which support those fields.
# Note: wordpad (write) and others do not support links.

RTF_HYPERLINKS         = NO
```

I set RTF_HYPERLINKS to "NO" to disable hyperlinks but I still get them:

```
Class Index
{tc "Hierarchical Index"} Class Hierarchy
This inheritance list is sorted roughly, but not completely, alphabetically:
```

What is the correct setting to cause Doxygen to not generate the hyperlinks or references?

Comment: Maybe AUTOLINK_SUPPORT = NO

Comment: #Toby thanks for the reply. That parameter does not turn off hyperlinks. However, when I searched for it, I realized that my doxygen version is out of date (was 1.6.3). I updated to v1.8.4 and with RTF_HYPERLINKS=NO, the hyperlinks are gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: Update to v1.8.4 and RTF_HYPERLINKS=NO